# Как исправить ошибку SyntaxError: invalid syntax File «», line 1?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Когда пытаюсь компилировать код, появляется следующая ошибка:

```
File "", line 1
& C:/Users/fbono/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe e:/CodeWORK/ada.py
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Забавно то, что если я перезапускаю ВС, то каких-либо ошибок не наблюдается. По истечении нескольких минут ошибка возобновляется, помогает только перезапуск ВСа.

Пробовал переустанавливать Пайтон - не помогло.

Сам код обычный, для теста.

```python
a = 24.4
b = '25'
c = 14.2
print (a + int(b) + c)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51540391/7485582